# Decode french in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I need to parse french string ("Vidéo") from UTF-8 file.
But I get `'Vid\xc3\xa9o'` instead of desired sting.

I tried decode('utf-8') but it will fail with following result:

```
'Vid\xe9o'
```

How to fix this encoding issue?

Comment: How are you displaying the value? Maybe your console can't display unicode characters, and "Vid\xc3\xa9o" is the correct internal representation of the string.

Comment: Kevin is right, this is an output issue, not a parsing issue.

Comment: Right, `'Vid\xc3\xa9o'` is the correct UTF-8, and `u'Vid\xe9o'` is one way to show the correct Unicode.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? It's actually crucial in this case.

Answer (score 3):

`'\xe9'` is the correct representation of the unicode 'é'. `\x` is the string escape sequence for a hexadecimal character and 'e9' is the hexadecimal value of the character 'é'. If you write the value of the string `'Vid\xe9o'` to a file and open it with a program which supports displaying unicode characters, it should show up as 'Vidéo'.